# What is the best way to make this type of infographic?

Tags: javascript

This [wonderful data science website](http://selfiecity.net/selfiexploratory/) has a beautiful slider-based way of simultaneously filtering and visualizing statistics of the filtered group. I'd like to make something similar, what are appropriate frameworks/methods/tutorials for doing this?

[image]

Comment: You might want to check out [the help center.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Opinion-based ("what is the best ...") questions and questions requesting recommendations on libraries/frameworks/etc. are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Perhaps you should check out [Software Recommendations.](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Two libraries I know could get the job done:

[D3.js](https://d3js.org/)

[vis.js](http://visjs.org/)

They both can handle complex visualization and data binding.